# Geonetworks Languages

Tags: geonetwork, internationalization

I've been trying to change the default language of geonetworks to portuguese but with no success.. Anyone know how can I add the portuguese language and then make portuguese language the default language of my geonetworks ?

Comment: What language is your internet browser set to?

Comment: My internet browser as portuguese language

Answer (score 1):

If you are building your own GeoNetwork from the sources you can modify the `language.default` and the `language.forceDefault` properties in [pom.xml](https://github.com/geonetwork/core-geonetwork/blob/e000a9166a505458b0fbf483e783b812b2797a88/pom.xml#L1253-L1259):

```
<!-- Default catalog language when accessing the home page
ie. http://localhost:8080/geonetwork. -->
<language.default>por</language.default>
<!-- Define if redirection should ignore HTTP headers,
Cookie or URL parameters. Set it to true to always redirect
to the default language. -->
<language.forceDefault>true</language.forceDefault>
```

If you are using the official WAR you can modify the `language.default` and `language.forceDefault` properties in `WEB-INF/config.properties`:

```
language.default=por
language.forceDefault=true
```

However, at this moment, there is no Portuguese language available in GN. For GeoNetwork 3.x the translations are managed in 
Transifex and there's a Portuguese translation (not complete), check it in:

https://www.transifex.com/geonetwork/core-geonetwork/

You can sign in in Transifex to collaborate in the translation.

Comment: I wanted to do the same for my language (Slovenian), but Transifex seems prohibitively hard to use:
1. Can't download existing translations without being part of the team
2. I asked to join the team a week ago and I still didn't get the confirmation

Why are those translations not available to everyone, even without signing into Transifex? I just can't think of a good reason.

Edit: finished the comment after accidentally pressing the Enter key

Comment: New translations are always welcomed. Thank you very much for your interest. Where did you ask for access? You should write to the users or developer mailing list, introducing yourself and saying what you are trying to do to add you to the translation team. https://www.geonetwork-opensource.org/community.html

Comment: I asked to join the team directly on the Transifex project page https://www.transifex.com/geonetwork/core-geonetwork/ by clicking the "Join team" button. I will ask for access on the mailing list shortly, thank you!